# Does anyone know a good tutorial for Tab bars?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, xib, tabbar

Does anyone know a good tutorial for Tab bars?

My app is currently a "view-based" app. I need a tutorial on how to make it so that my main nib loads the view from other nibs, and when I click different tabs, it loads other nibs.

Thanks

Comment: Why separte nibs? Check out the XMLPerformane sample project on the dev center. UITabBarController handles all the lazy loading and what not for free. You can set it all up in IB in one nib. You just add a tab bar controller to you nib and then add your view/nav controllers to that. That XML app is the best example of how simple it is. If you did this in code you would just create a UITabBarController and pass it an array of UIViewControllers then add yourTabBarController.view as a subview to your window. Made this a comment since it doesn't answer your question about separte nibs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone Developers' Cookbook by Erica Sadun has a good recipe for tabbars on page 126, including customising the bar from a list of controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked around this site?

http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/

Answer (score 1):

TheElements sample code in the Apple SDK -- lots of links on StackOverflow and elsewhere for combining with navigation controllers (always add nav controllers to the tab bar, not vice versa!)